# Return value in Lisp

Tags: recursion, lisp, return

So i started learning Lisp yesterday and started doing some problems.

Something I'm having a hard time doing is inserting/deleting atoms in a list while keeping the list the same ex: `(delete 'b '(g a (b) l))` will give me `(g a () l)`.

Also something I'm having trouble with is this problem.
I'm suppose to check if anywhere in the list the atom exist.

I traced through it and it says it returns `T` at one point, but then gets overriden by a `nil`.

Can you guys help :)?

I'm using `(appear-anywhere 'a '((b c) g ((a))))`

at the 4th function call it returns `T` but then becomes `nil`.

```
(defun appear-anywhere (a l)
  (cond
   ((null l) nil)
   ((atom (car l))
    (cond
     ((equal (car l) a) T)
     (T (appear-anywhere a (cdr l)))))
   (T (appear-anywhere a (car l))(appear-anywhere a (cdr l)))))
```

Comment: Note that there is a `delete` function in Common Lisp. It does not have the above behavior. If you define your own function `delete`, then the behavior is no longer defined by the Common Lisp standard and is basically up to whatever your Lisp does with that situation. You can, of course, make your own symbol package (a kind of namespace) which has a `delete` symbol, not related to `cl:delete`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at one obvious problem:

```
(defun appear-anywhere (a l)
  (cond
   ((null l) nil)
   ((atom (car l))
    (cond
     ((equal (car l) a) T)
     (T (appear-anywhere a (cdr l)))))
   (T (appear-anywhere a (car l))(appear-anywhere a (cdr l)))))
```

Think about the last line of above.

Let's format it slightly differently.

```
(defun appear-anywhere (a l)
  (cond
   ((null l) nil)
   ((atom (car l))
    (cond
     ((equal (car l) a) T)
     (T (appear-anywhere a (cdr l)))))
   (T
    (appear-anywhere a (car l))
    (appear-anywhere a (cdr l)))))
```

The last three lines: So as a default (that's why the `T` is there) the last two forms will be computed. First the first one and then the second one. The value of the first form is never used or returned.

That's probably not what you want.

Currently your code just returns something when the value of `a` appears anywhere in the rest of the list. The first form is never really used.

Hint: What is the right logical connector?